# How do i make a splash screen in Action Extension in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen

So, I'm trying to create a splash screen for an action extension, since i got some work i would like to do before presenting the app.

How can i do this?

I've added a launch screen in the extension and checked the "Use as launch screen" flag, but it doesn't show.

I'm not sure that its even loaded since i'm not allowed to create a VC for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you need to create your own view controller and make the animations there until you actually finish your app preparations. You might want to take a look at something already implemented like this one: https://github.com/sachinkesiraju/SKSplashView

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I was thinking the same actually, but are you sure that this is won't just be rejected from the App Store?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to be rejected as long as you don't use any copy right protected images, shapes and logos of certain companies. You can set this view controller while you finish your app preparations as the root view controller or as child on top of your initial one.